# Is there a way to embed and sandbox a web page with web component

Tags: javascript, web-component

I followed this link: https://sebastiandedeyne.com/embed-a-web-page-with-a-web-component-and-the-shadow-dom/
I expected to get an equal to sandbox javascript but but only get the static page witout javascript and css applied and dont get code if i use url version.
How to do it properly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simple template</title>
  <script src="main2.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Simple template</h1>
  <embedded-webview src="https://www.google.com/index.html"></embedded-webview>


</body>

</html>
```

main2.js file

```
class EmbeddedWebview extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
    fetch(this.getAttribute('src'))
      .then(response => response.html())
      .then(html => {
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
        shadow.innerHTML = html;
      });
  }
}
 
window.customElements.define(
  'embedded-webview',
  EmbeddedWebview
);
```

I'm expet to get an sandboxt to javascript.
Maybe if anyone could recommend to me any already done webcomponent

Comment: There is a built-in element for this purpose: [`<iframe>`: The Inline Frame element - HTML: HyperText Markup Language | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: ``HTML Imports`` (https://web.dev/imports/) was a Google only party and never implemented as a standard. So your fetch can only fetch HTML, ``<script>`` will not execute. As said use an ``<iframe>``

Comment: iframe is unapplicable because the external html autoajust this size to screen as my html code. And the iframe only have fixed size. The external html code is not really external. There is an way to convert itself to webcomponent.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75126669/is-there-a-way-to-embed-and-sandbox-a-web-page-with-web-component?noredirect=1#comment132574215_75126669) @DanielFigueiredo In short: no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using now an aproach that works.
I'm usin an iframe with autoresize hability , starting with fullscreen resize.